# How to work with JWT in MVC application where is some JavaScript part using IdentityServer4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have Asp.Net MVC Core application and inside it is the React JavaScript application.

I would like to share the access token between MVC part and React JavaScript part.

I've used for generating access token the `IdentityServer4` with Implicit Flow.

I've used the `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` middleware which store the token inside cookie probable but this cookie is not readable from JavaScript.

How can I pass the access token from MVC to the JavaScript? I want to use in JavaScript this token for calling and API from React.

Finally I want to store the token in cookie for MVC (it's okay) and for React part in the localStorage - but I don't know how send the token from MVC to the React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From React, you could call your MVC server and return the token to React:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<String> GetAccessToken()
    {
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i achieve that I will have store access token like this? That will be possible get like this: `HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token")`